# Is there a possibility to select all alternatives in a group

Tags: regex, regex-group

In my regex there is a group that has 3 alternatives. After the regex test, only the last appeared alternative is selected into the select group.
Is there a possibility to select all occurred alternatives?

I used `regex101` to test my results.

https://regex101.com/r/iBxX9V/4

If that doesn't work for you, here's an automatically generated code to test this regex:

```js
const regex = /clone\s+([^ \/]+)\s+([^ \/]+)(?:\s*(?:--(flag1|flag2|flag3)))*$/gm;
const str = `clone
clone a b
clone a b --flag1
clone a b  --flag1 --flag2
clone a b --flag1 --unknown
clone a b -- --
clone a b    --flag1   --flag2 --flag3`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

At the moment the regex match will only return the last occurrence of an alternative.

Example for `clone a b    --flag1   --flag2 --flag3`:

```
"match":[ 
    "clone a b    --flag1   --flag2 --flag3",
    "a",
    "b",
    "flag3"
],
```

I wonder if there is a way to get

```
"match":[ 
    "clone a b    --flag1   --flag2 --flag3",
    "a",
    "b",
    ["flag1", "flag2", "flag3"]
],
```

or

```
"match":[ 
    "clone a b    --flag1   --flag2 --flag3",
    "a",
    "b",
    "flag1",
    "flag2",
    "flag3"
],
```

NOTE: The flags can appear in random order.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/iBxX9V/7

Any help and hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just do a separate group for each flag, then you'd have them all caught

```perl
clone\s+([^ \/]+)\s+([^ \/]+)(?:\s*(?:(--flag1)*\s*(--flag2)*\s*(--flag3)*))*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/iBxX9V/6

Comment: Oh, I was hoping that there would be way with less code, but this definitely works, so thanks a bunch!!!

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice this at the beginning. And I forgot to mention this in the question at start.
The groups are not selected if they are not ordered :(
https://regex101.com/r/iBxX9V/7

Comment: Ok so if you want specific flags only (not any string) and they need to appear in random order, and also be absent, then we can't do it via a capturing group. Easiest you could do is to just capture all the flags to one group, then split it by space and check each flag individually with code. I.e.: `clone\s+([^ \/]+)\s+([^ \/]+)\s*(?<flags>.*)$`. This will put all the flags substring to "flags" matching group, see https://regex101.com/r/iBxX9V/8

Comment: Yeap. I ended up using some JS to properly get the flags, and just used initial regex version to make that the pattern is correct.

It doesn't seem like there is way to do what I want with regex. Thanks for your help anyway. I will mark this is answer.